# Bounding an $L^2$ function (with Cubic...)

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f(x) \in H^1(R)$. Is it possible to bound $\int f^4 dx \leq \|f\|_{H^1(R)} ^3$.  Likewise, it is possible to say $\int f^3 dx \leq \|f\|_{H^1(R)} ^3$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elementary argument: suppose $f\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$, we have that

$$ f^2(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x 2 f(y) f'(y) \mathrm{d}y \leq 2 \|f\|_{L^2} \|f'\|_{L^2} \leq  \|f\|_{L^2}^2 + \|f'\|_{L^2}$$

Hence, assuming your norm for $H^1$ is defined as

$$ \|f\|_{H^1}^2 = \|f\|_{L^2}^2 + \|f'\|_{L^2}^2 $$

you have that

$$ \|f\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|f\|_{H^1} $$

We also have for $n \geq 2$

$$ \int f^n \mathrm{d}x \leq \int |f|^n \mathrm{d}x \leq \|f\|^{n-2}_{L^\infty} \int |f|^2 \mathrm{d}x = \|f\|^{n-2}_{L^\infty} \|f\|^2_{L^2} $$

Combining everything above and using a density argument of $C^1_c$ in $H^1$ and in $L^{n}$ you have the desired inequalities. If you have differing normalisations for the $H^1$ norms you will pick up constant factors in the inequality, but in general an inequality of the form $\|f\|_{L^n} \leq C_n \|f\|_{H^1}$ holds for $n \geq 2$ and some universal constant $C_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will keep this computational trick/ intuition in mind from now on.

Comment: Willie- The fact that we are in one-dimension is quite crucial here ? I think yes, but I just want to make sure. Regards-

Comment: @Jiro: yes. Essentially the above demonstrates the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality in one dimension. The appropriate inequality (in terms of the $L^p$ spaces) is dimension dependent.

Comment: Willie- sorry, I forgot to see this earlier. I was wondering if we can get $H^1$-norm cubed...

Comment: @Jiro: $|\int f^3| \leq \int |f|^3 = \|f\|_{L^3}^3$. Or, simply, set $n = 3$ in the final displayed equation in my answer.